# How to return value from recursive function instead of printing to console?

Tags: python-3.x, depth-first-search

I would like to get all paths between two nodes `i` and `j` in a graph. I am using DFS to accomplish this. The code works. However, I don't want to `print` the path to the console (see `print(path)` line in `searchPaths(self, i, j, visited, path)` function). I'd like to `return` it. However, because it is a recursive function, `return` is not working. What would be the proper way to return `path` so I can use it for other calculations?

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, edges=dict()):
        '''Initializes a Graph. Variables:
            - edges: dictionary with edge tuples as keys (i,j) and
            weight w_ij as values.'''
        self.edges = edges


    def searchPaths(self, i, j, visited, path):
        '''Searches all possible paths from node i to node j.'''
        # Set current node as visited and store it in path 
        visited[i] = True 
        path.append(i)
        # If current node is not same as destination, recursively
        # search adjacent nodes.        
        if i != j:
            for u in self.adjacencyList[1].get(i, []):
                if visited[u] == False:
                    self.searchPaths(u, j, visited, path)
        else:
            print(path)
        # Remove current vertex from path and mark as unvisited
        path.pop()
        visited[i] = False


    def printAllPaths(self, i, j):
        '''Print all possible paths from node i to node j.'''
        # Set all nodes as not visited 
        visited = {n: False for n in self.nodes}
        # Create a list to store the path 
        path = []
        # Call recursive function to search for paths
        self.searchPaths(i, j, visited, path)

    @property
    def adjacencyList(self):
        '''Returns the adjacency list.'''
        ingoing, outgoing = {}, {}
        for edge in self.edges.keys():
            i, j = edge[0], edge[1]
            outgoing[i] = outgoing.get(i, []) + [j]
            ingoing[j] = ingoing.get(j, []) + [i]
        ingoing = {k:set(v) for k,v in ingoing.items()}
        outgoing = {k:set(v) for k,v in outgoing.items()}
        return ingoing, outgoing
```

As a motivating example, the following edges can be used: `edges = {(1, 2): 1, (2, 1): 2, (2, 3): 2, (3, 2): 3, (3, 5): 2, (5, 4): 8, (5, 6): 9, (7, 6): 4, (7, 8): 4, (8, 9): 1, (8, 10): 3, (9, 10): 2, (10, 7): 5, (10, 11): 8, (12, 13): 3, (13, 14): 1, (14, 12): 2, (15, 14): 4}`. When searching the paths from `i=7` to `j=11` one should get two paths: `[7,8,9,10,11]` and `[7,8,10,11]`.

Comment: Return should work , provided your function terminates, and you are able to describe the termination.

Comment: I tried replacing `print()` with `return`. It doesn't work.

Comment: If you simply replace print with return , it won't work because only your last call is returning anything, you need to capture all the intermediate return in your for-loop , especially when doing DFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see if we can make this work .

**Analysis of your code**

This is peculiar : why would you mark as unvisited your nodes ?
This probably won't change anything, or worse might even cause problems in your code.

`# Remove current vertex from path and mark as unvisited
        path.pop()
        visited[i] = False`

**Goal definition**

We wish for :

- the last call to return a path.
- the intermediate call to be the bridge to relay the information ( returning all paths)

**Attempt**

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, edges=dict()):
        '''Initializes a Graph. Variables:
            - edges: dictionary with edge tuples as keys (i,j) and
            weight w_ij as values.'''
        self.edges = edges
        self.get_nodes()

    def get_nodes(self):
        self.nodes = set()
        for i,j in self.edges:
            self.nodes.add(i)
            self.nodes.add(j)

    def searchPaths(self, i, j, visited, path):
        '''Searches all possible paths from node i to node j.'''
        # Set current node as visited and store it in path 
        visiting = dict(visited)
        visiting[i] = True 
        aux = path[:]
        aux.append(i)
        # If current node is not same as destination, recursively
        # search adjacent nodes. 
        all_paths=[]
        if i != j:
            for u in self.adjacencyList[1].get(i, []):
                if visiting[u] == False:
                    all_paths += self.searchPaths(u, j, visiting, aux)

        else:
            print(aux)
            all_paths += [aux[:]]
        return all_paths



    def printAllPaths(self, i, j):
        '''Print all possible paths from node i to node j.'''
        # Set all nodes as not visited 
        visited = {n: False for n in self.nodes}
        # Create a list to store the path 
        path = []
        # Call recursive function to search for paths
        return self.searchPaths(i, j, visited, path)

    @property
    def adjacencyList(self):
        '''Returns the adjacency list.'''
        ingoing, outgoing = {}, {}
        for edge in self.edges.keys():
            i, j = edge[0], edge[1]
            outgoing[i] = outgoing.get(i, []) + [j]
            ingoing[j] = ingoing.get(j, []) + [i]
        ingoing = {k:set(v) for k,v in ingoing.items()}
        outgoing = {k:set(v) for k,v in outgoing.items()}
        return ingoing, outgoing
```

Comment: I tried your code but it doesn't work as intended. I edited my question to show the entire class definition and added a motivating example at the end. Maybe that can help.

Comment: Okay it works now, for good. As I suspected the pop and revert validating is only because of alisasing

Comment: That worked great! Could you explain why is aliasing happening here?

Comment: Since you are modifying your input in every call , in the for loop, your are aliasing your ``visited``as well as your ``path``, meaning that those call have a pointer to the same instance of the object. Therefore, unvalidating it was a good call, however, this might mean doing duplicated actions. To prevent that , you need to properly copy the instance to another one :)

Comment: Found new issue. If I now have a cycle, let's say an edge (n,n) exists, I get multiple paths that repeat the node! That shouldn't happen!

Comment: If you are looking for all the path from a two points, and there is a cycle , it is only fair to assume the path can go through that cycle ?

Comment: No. A path is defined as an ordered sequence of DISTINCT vertices. If vertices are repeated, that's a walk, not a path.

Comment: Then simply duplicate your adjacencyList creation , and remove "self_edges"

Comment: Yes, I thought the same thing. However, the problem here is the implementation of DFS. There is a mistake there because DFS doesn't repeat nodes. If it was visited, it is not re-visited. Thus, I believe the aliasing issue we had before is now creating another problem.

Comment: Found the problem , was checking on visited rather than visiting

Comment: Excellent! I missed that!